Extra Cosmos DB calls for using Cosmos SDK 3.37.0
I am using cosmos db to do a simple retrieval like this
public async Task<bool> FindIfDuplicateAsync(string instructionId)
{
    var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition("Select c.evolveId FROM c where c.instructionId = @instructionId")
        .WithParameter("@instructionId", instructionId);
    var response =  await FindAllItemsAsync<MinimalEvolvePaymentRequest>(queryDefinition, null);
    if (response.Count == 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}

FindAllItemsAsync is defined like this
protected virtual async Task<List<T>> FindAllItemsAsync<T>(QueryDefinition queryDefinition, QueryRequestOptions requestOptions = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    List<T> documents = new List<T>();
    using (FeedIterator<T> feedIterator = Container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(queryDefinition, null, requestOptions))
    {
        while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            documents.AddRange(await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync(cancellationToken));
        }
    }

    return documents;
}

And In application insights I see the logs like this, some of them taking seconds to complete.  Usually the retrieval is very fast but in some cases, it looks like this:
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2020-06-01
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/payments/colls/paymentRequests
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/payments/colls/paymentRequests/docs
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/WXteAA==/colls/WXteAIy5we0=/pkranges
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/WXteAA==/colls/WXteAIy5we0=/pkranges
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com//addresses/?$resolveFor=dbs%2fWXteAA%3d%3d%2fcolls%2fWXteAIy5we0%3d%2fdocs&$filter=protocol eq rntbd&$partitionKeyRangeIds=0
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/payments/colls/partnerLedger
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/payments/colls/partnerLedger/docs
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/WXteAA==/colls/WXteALWILLw=/pkranges
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/WXteAA==/colls/WXteALWILLw=/pkranges
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com//addresses/?$resolveFor=dbs%2fWXteAA%3d%3d%2fcolls%2fWXteALWILLw%3d%2fdocs&$filter=protocol eq rntbd&$partitionKeyRangeIds=0
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/

In a regular call the logs look like this:
 https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/payments/colls/paymentRequests/docs
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/payments/colls/partnerLedger/docs

Why is this happening, where are these additional GET calls coming from?
The document has one non-hierarchical partition key and there is no RU throttling.
I have abstracted building cosmos client to a NuGet package and this is how I am doing it
protected virtual CosmosClient CosmosClient
{
    get
    {
        if (_cosmosClient != null)
        {
            return _cosmosClient;
        }

        CosmosClientBuilder cosmosClientBuilder = GetCosmosClientBuilder();

        cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithApplicationName(ApplicationName);
        cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithApplicationPreferredRegions(ApplicationPreferredRegions);
        cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithApplicationRegion(ApplicationRegion);

        if (HttpClientFactory is not null)
            cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithHttpClientFactory(() => HttpClientFactory.CreateClient());

        if (AllowBulkExecution.HasValue)
            cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithBulkExecution(AllowBulkExecution.Value);

        if (ConsistencyLevel.HasValue)
            cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Value);

        // Don't set the CosmosSerializer unless it's not null (the setter has validation)
        if (CosmosSerializer != null)
            cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithCustomSerializer(CosmosSerializer);

        // Don't set the CosmosSerializationOptions unless it's not null (the setter has validation)
        if (CosmosSerializationOptions != null)
            cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithSerializerOptions(CosmosSerializationOptions);

        if (EnableContentResponseOnWrite.HasValue)
            cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithContentResponseOnWrite(EnableContentResponseOnWrite.Value);

        if (LimitToEndpoint.HasValue)
            cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithLimitToEndpoint(LimitToEndpoint.Value);

        if (RequestTimeout.HasValue)
            cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithRequestTimeout(RequestTimeout.Value);

        if (MaxRetryWaitTimeOnThrottledRequests.HasValue && MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests.HasValue)
            cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithThrottlingRetryOptions(MaxRetryWaitTimeOnThrottledRequests.Value, MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests.Value);

        cosmosClientBuilder = cosmosClientBuilder.WithConnectionModeDirect();

        _cosmosClient = cosmosClientBuilder.Build();

        return _cosmosClient;
    }
}



it would be very helpful for you to provide all the GET entries as text, since images are difficult to read (and impossible to copy/paste) - see Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Aside from that: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is. FYI you should check to see if there is any throttling due to not enough RU/sec availability. There's no way to know why some of your operations take 400+ ms (although that doesn't seem like an unreasonable amount of time) - we don't know your schema, partitioning, quantity of docs returned, etc)

This is part of the Direct Connectivity initialization.
https://{{cosmosResource}}.documents.azure.com:443/

The above is the SDK fetching the Account configuration (which regions, which consistency, etc). It happens once during initialization and once every 5 minutes as a background refresh.
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/payments/colls/paymentRequests

This happens once during initialization, it fetches the Container information (which partition key definition path + other things).
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com/dbs/WXteAA==/colls/WXteAIy5we0=/pkranges

This happens once during initialization (there might be 2 calls at that moment), it fetches the list of physical partitions. It would only happen again if the physical partitions split.
https://{{cosmosResource}}-eastus.documents.azure.com//addresses/?$resolveFor=dbs%2fWXteAA%3d%3d%2fcolls%2fWXteAIy5we0%3d%2fdocs&$filter=protocol eq rntbd&$partitionKeyRangeIds=0

This happens once during initialization of the partition, explained in the first link. It is fetching the TCP addresses of the partition to establish TCP connections.
Assuming you are using the CosmosClient as a singleton (you are not creating it for every query, which would be wrong), then most of these should not repeat for every operation. In your screenshot and logs I see the /pkranges and /addresses more than once, which would mean, you are not following the Singleton pattern.

I am using the Singleton pattern  // Inject service dependencies
services.AddSingleton<IPaymentCosmosDBService, PaymentCosmosDBService>();

You might be injecting your IPaymentCosmosDBService type but how is the CosmosClient used? There is no way the CosmosClient is calling /pkranges twice in the same instance one after the other if they are using the same object instance.

I have abstracted that and I updated the question on how I am building the CosmosClient

If you are still seeing the list of requests on the screenshot (multiple times /addresses and /pkranges more than the initial 2 times) then something is creating new clients. The code you attached is no thread-safe (if it's called concurrently it will create 2 clients), maybe that might be one reason? Regardless, the URLs that you are asking about are explained in my answer.

Another possibility now that I think about it is that you are using multiple Containers and yes, the first request to each container will need to get the partitions and addresses for that container. But subsequent requests will not.
